# 'polymer' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: polymer, command-prompt, polymer-cli

I recently installed nodejs, bower. Then, I installed polymer using this command:

`npm install -g polymer`

Then, I added the polymer install path:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Then, I am trying to do `polymer init`. I am seeing this error:

> 'polymer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Can someone please suggest what I can do to get polymer working?

Comment: did you try it in new command prompt window?

Comment: Try installing some other component like `polyserve` or `http-server` and see if you are facing the same problem

Comment: No. Still no luck. I did try it out in a new cmd window.

Comment: try some other npm package

Comment: I did `npm install -g gulp`. After that, I was able to do `gulp --version` and I got a result: > [05:01:02] CLI version 3.9.1

Comment: was there any error while installing `polymer`? Can you reinstall it and try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line tool is called polymer-cli.  Install that

`npm install -g polymer-cli`

Answer (score 8):

Adding on from akc42's answer:

1. Make sure you have installed the Polymer Cli

   - from a command prompt type: `npm install -g polymer-cli`
2. Make sure the npm global install folder is part of the path

   - edit "system environment variables"
   - add reference to where npm is installed to the PATH: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`
3. Open new command window
4. Type: `polymer --version`
5. If polymer can be found, it should display the version of polymer installed

Comment: was helpful for me

Comment: Thanks @Stuy1974, and if, like me and using an app like VS Code to use polymer-cli and after updating the path you still don't see polymer --version, try restarting the app.

Comment: "add reference to where npm is installed to the PATH: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm" that was my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

install polymer-cli using npm.

```
$ yarn global add polymer-cli
# or... 
$ npm install -g polymer-cli
```

For more: [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-cli)